# Parseing CSV data returned from the Journey History Download EndPoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

how do you parse the csv data from the Journey History Download Endpoint?
I'm getting the response, then splitting the rows using `responseData.split("\n");`
I then want to upsert the data to a DE, using the comma delimiter to split the columns. I get an 'unable to retrieve security descriptor for this iframe error' for this code:

```
 var csvRow = csvLines[i].split(',');
    var transactionTime = csvRow[0];
    var contactKey = csvRow[1];
    var status = csvRow[2];
    var definitionId = csvRow[3];
    var definitionName = csvRow[4];
    var activityId = csvRow[5];
    var activityName = csvRow[6];
    var activityType = csvRow[7];
  

   var upsertDE = Platform.Function.UpsertDE(
    "JourneyHistoryData", 
   ["ContactKey", "Status", "TransactionTime", "DefinitionId", "DefinitionName", "ActivityId", "ActivityName", "ActivityType"],
   [contactKey[i], status[i], transactionTime[i], definitionId[i], definitionName[i], activityId[i], activityName[i], activityType[i]]
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UpsertDE` function has only 3 parameters while it should have 5 ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertDE.html)).

The 2nd and 3rd parameters should represent a key & value pair that represents the Contact Key.

Try with this:

```
var upsertDE = Platform.Function.UpsertDE(
    "JourneyHistoryData", 
    ["ContactKey"], 
    [contactKey[i]], 
    ["Status", "TransactionTime", "DefinitionId", "DefinitionName", "ActivityId", "ActivityName", "ActivityType"], 
    [status[i], transactionTime[i], definitionId[i], definitionName[i], activityId[i], activityName[i], activityType[i]]
)
```